# Unity ScrollViewScope horizontal scroll not working with EditorGUILayout

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I need to use EditorGUI.IndentLevelScope and it only work with EditorGUILayout like LabelField, Foldout, not in GUILayout like Label.

here is my code

```
                using (var midScroll = new EditorGUILayout.ScrollViewScope(midSPos, true, true))
                {
                    using (new EditorGUI.IndentLevelScope(1))
                    {
                        midSPos = midScroll.scrollPosition;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                        {
                            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("This is a EditorGUILayout.LabelField. This is a EditorGUILayout.LabelField.", GUI.skin.GetStyle("LinkLabel"));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Vertical work but not Horizontal
Pic: https://gyazo.com/70382d83222dc7fc2db54c4745836dfc

same code with GUILayout.Label work both
what do i miss

Comment: sounds like you haven't really told your scroll view the vertical width it shall cover ... hard to tell without more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up I found a solution for Label by adding an empty `PrefixLabel` in front and back to **GUILayout** again, the scroll now works.

```
HorizontalScope
    EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("");
    GUILayout.Label("content");
```

But still, have some issues with my **foldout** like this since I can't add **HorizontalScope** to it.

```
InitRow(row row)
{
    if (isShowing = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(isShowing, "Foldout"))
    {
        InitRow(child);
    }
}
```